# Update SQL table with most recent value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am building a database (SQL Server 2008) for an application to track server backups. Each day we get a report showing the status of last night's backups.

When a backup is successful (backup_ok = 'OK'), then I have an UPDATE query which sets the `last_recovery_date` to the `backup_date`. Where I am struggling is when a backup is not successful/NOT OK.

In the example below, the `last_recovery_date` for VM001 should be 2018-10-23. What should the T-SQL code for this be?

```
server | backup_date | backup_ok | last_recovery_date
-------+-------------+-----------+-------------------
VM001  | 2018-10-24  | NOT OK    |
VM002  | 2018-10-24  | OK        | 2018-10-24
VM001  | 2018-10-23  | OK        | 2018-10-23
VM002  | 2018-10-23  | OK        | 2018-10-23
```

Comment: As a side note: You should consider a newer SQL Version. Support for 2008 R2 ends on 7/9/2019 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Always provide code of what you have tried and what errors you get, or what the expected outcome should be.

Answer (score 3):

You need `update` statement, so you can use `subquery` :

```
update t
      set t.last_recovery_date = (select max(t1.last_recovery_date) 
                                  from table t1 
                                  where t.server = t1.server and t1.backup_ok = 'OK'
                                 )
from table t
where backup_ok = 'NOT OK';
```

Comment: Add to the subquery `and t1.backup_ok = 'OK'`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled. . . Yes it is also needed. Thanks.

Comment: Im unclear on what the t and t1 in the code refer to. If the table name (t) is daily_backups, what is t1?
I checked to verify, and the SQL version (in case it matters) is actually 2014.

Comment: @Covfefe. .  You just need to replace `table` with your actual table name (`daily_backups`) & `t` & `t1` is a table alias `t` is outer query table reference & `t1` is a `subquery` table reference.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this query will be helpfull for you .Once make a try

```
SELECT * INTO #TEST FROM (
SELECT'VM001' [server] ,'2018-10-24'backup_date ,'NOT OK'backup_ok ,NULL last_recovery_date
UNION ALL SELECT'VM002','2018-10-24','OK    ','2018-10-24'
UNION ALL SELECT'VM001','2018-10-23','OK    ','2018-10-23'
UNION ALL SELECT'VM002','2018-10-23','OK    ','2018-10-23'
)AS A


SELECT * FROM #TEST

UPDATE T SET T.last_recovery_date=A.backup_date  
FROM #TEST T
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT MAX(backup_date)AS backup_date 
              FROM #TEST T1 WHERE T.[SERVER]=T1.[SERVER] 
              AND T1.backup_ok='OK'
             ) AS A
WHERE T.backup_ok='NOT OK'

SELECT * FROM #TEST
```